# Allocating memory and freeing correctly?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, free

This is the code for allocating memory for 2 Arrays of uknown size. N is given by the user:

```
  K=malloc(N*sizeof(int));
if(K==NULL){
 // printf("Sorry, cannot allocate memory\n");
    return -1;
} 

for(i = 0;i < N;i++){
  C = malloc(N * sizeof(int *));
  if (C == NULL){
   return -1;
}

for (i = 0 ; i < N ; i++) {
  *(C+i) = malloc(K[i] * sizeof(int));
  if (*(C+i) == NULL){
   return -1; }
}
}
```

Both arrays are filled with numbers given by the user.
And to free them:

```
    for (i=0 ; i < N ; i++){

   for (i=0 ; i < N ; i++){
    free(*(C+i));
                          }
     free(C);
                           }
void free(void*K);
```

by debugging with gbd i come across this error

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_int_free (av=0x10102464c457f, p=0x8005770, have_lock=) at malloc.c:4304
4304    malloc.c: No such file or directory.

by using valgrind to go deeper into this error it seems, that i have no leaks.What could be the problem?

Comment: Remember that for any pointer or array `p` and index `i` the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`. That means when you use `*(C+i)` it's the same as `C[i]`. The latter is easier to read and shorter to write.

Comment: More related to your question, when you do `C = malloc(N * sizeof(int *));` inside a loop, you will have plenty of memory leaks. Only the allocation from the *last* iteration will be available from the pointer `C`. Also note that you never anywhere initialize `K[i]`, it will have an *indeterminate* (and seemingly random/garbage) value.

Comment: `void free(void*K);` doesn't do anything. It is just a prototype declaration of `free`, which you probably got already by including `<stdlib.h>`. Just call `free(K);`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the contents of arrays K and C are filled with info that the user gives.I edited it so it maks more sense

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i = 0;i < N;i++){int *));
  if (C == NULL){
   return -1;
}
```

with every iteration the previous allocated memory is lost as the pointer is assigned with the reference to the newly allocated memory block.

if your intention was to change the size of the allocated memory you should use `realloc` instead

Assuming C is `int **` (as per you program logic)

```
C = NULL;    
for(i = 0;i < N;i++){
    void *tmp = realloc(C, N * sizeof(*C));
    if (tmp == NULL){
        free(C);
        return -1;
    }
    C = tmp;
}
```